# Issues with controllers in Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, isolate-scope

I'm trying to update some code in a small personal project which uses angular to conform to better practices, and I have heard that the future of Angular can be mimicked in a way by putting a lot of functionality into controllers of directives. I'm not sure how correct my understanding is but it seems like a clean way of organizing code.

Anyways, to get to the point of my issue, I can't seem to get the isolate scope to work when I give my directive a controller. I've been googling my brains out trying to figure out what the issue is, and I saw many topics about it, but none which solved my issue.

Here's a code fragment:

```
angular.module('myCongresspersonApp')
  .directive('congressPersonPane', function () {

    var controller = [function() {

    }];

    return {
      templateUrl: 'app/congressPersonPane/congressPersonPane.html',
      restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                congressPerson: '=info'
            }//,
      // controller: controller,
      // controllerAs: 'paneCtrl',
      // bindToController: true
    };
  });
```

This is really just a way to test before I move functionality around, but when I uncomment those lines, I no longer have access to the isolate scope I pass in and all the data accessed through that is gone (it is an array object in a ng-repeat).

I also have a similar problem in a directive which sits inside this directive. That problem makes me even more confused, as I can correctly use a method if I define it under the $scope, but when I use controllerAs, I cannot use that method. So I am pretty stumped as I pulled this implementation (to remove scope) from [this website](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-6-using-controllers) (mentioned by Lauren below)

here's the code for that:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myCongresspersonApp')
  .directive('voteRecord', function () {

        var controller = ['$scope', 'sunlightAPI', function ($scope, sunlightAPI) {
            var voteCtrl = this;
            voteCtrl.voteInfo = [];
            voteCtrl.test = 'Test';
            voteCtrl.pageNumber = 1;
            voteCtrl.repId = '';
            console.log('inside controller definition');

            voteCtrl.getVotingRecord = function(repId) {
              console.log('inside method');
              voteCtrl.repId = repId;
              var promiseUpdate = sunlightAPI.getVotes(repId, pageNumber);
              promiseUpdate.then(function(votes) {
                console.log('fulfilled promise');
                voteCtrl.voteInfo = votes;
                console.log(voteCtrl.voteInfo);
              }, function(reason) {
                console.log('Failed: ' + reason);
              }, function(update) {
                console.log('Update: ' + update);
              });
      };

      voteCtrl.nextPage = function() {
        voteCtrl.pageNumber++;
        voteCtrl.getVotingRecord(voteCtrl.repId, voteCtrl.pageNumber);
      };

      voteCtrl.previousPage = function() {
        voteCtrl.pageNumber--;
        voteCtrl.getVotingRecord(voteCtrl.repId, voteCtrl.pageNumber);
      };

        }];

    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        repId: '=representative'
      },
      controller: controller,
      contollerAs: 'voteCtrl',
            bindToController: true,
      templateUrl: 'app/voteRecord/voteRecord.html',
    };
  });
```

I'm not sure if that issue is related to this issue or not, but they seem similar. Any help or directions to resources which could help would be really appreciated, as I don't want to be writing code where my conventions are constantly changing because I don't fully understand why one thing works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand what your problem is, but it sounds like you are having problems accessing `$scope` from the controller. You can actually pass in the scope to the controller, like this:

```
angular.module('myCongresspersonApp')
  .directive('congressPersonPane', function () {

    var myController = function($scope) {
      // use $scope in here
    };

    return {
      templateUrl: 'app/congressPersonPane/congressPersonPane.html',
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        congressPerson: '=info'
      },
      controller: ['$scope', myController]
    };
  });
```

[This](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-6-using-controllers) blog post details how to use controllers in your directives. Also the Angular documentation will explain more too. Good luck!

Comment: I've just updated my post so it's a little more clear. I'm actually looking to remove the $scope and using controllerAs (I actually used the website you linked in order to figure this out, but apparently I either did something wrong or that isn't 100% correct). When I don't use controllerAs and instead use $scope, everything works fine.

Comment: I see. Is there anyway you could post your code in a jsfiddle or anything? I'm not that familiar with controllerAs, but from googling it looks like "this" will replace "$scope". Your code will break at the "voteCtrl.nextPage" and "voteCtrl.previousPage" definitions because you have defined them outside of the scope of the "var controller" definition. [This blog post](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html) seems to explain it very well. In your controller definition, you can access the scope with the **this** keyword. Hope this helps!

Comment: Those methods are within the controller, however weird tabs/spaces inconsistencies makes it appear strange in the stack overflow editor. Use the ']' to tell where it ends. I appreciate you trying to help, but I've already read everything you've posted before I even came to ask the question. And as you can see, I've set the var voteCtrl = this; in the beginning of my controller, which is just a way of keeping consistency between controller and the html template which would use the same name for the controller defined in controllerAs. Thank you though for attempting to help.